# Which opinion of the Rambam is followed, the Mishneh Torah or the Responsum?

Tags: halacha-theory, rambam, responsa, mishneh-torah

If there is a contradiction between something the Rambam wrote in the Mishneh Torah and his responsum letters, which is considered his final ruling? Is there a general rule or is it a case by case?

Comment: Do you have a specific example?

Comment: Most cases is tashuvoth->mt->mn I think Mori gafei7 talks bout this.

Comment: I hate "rules" like this. They never end up holding.

Comment: Was the Teshuva in question written before or after he wrote Mishneh Torah?

Comment: @DoubleAA i think that's a hard question to answer considering the MT was revised several times and IIRC scholars are not 100% sure which copy, if any, that they have is final-final

Comment: @please Mori gafei7 brings down in his MT what he believed to be the last revision. He brings down in comments where the changes were made from his families manuscript or to his families manuscript. Also he says that there is a clear contradiction between Morah navuchim n the mt in regards to shalua7 hakan. N he says the rambam wrote the mn after the mt n we hold the hashqofo n halocho from the mn n not the mt.

Comment: Great question. It's a problem that is not limited to the Rambam, you can find the same phenomenon among other poskim. For example, the [Maharil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_ben_Moshe_Levi_Moelin) "contradicts" himself regarding when one removes shoes before the [Ninth of Av](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tisha_B%27Av). Does one take them off at home, or before Ma'ariv? That depends whether you read the responsa or the "Customs" (מנהגי מהרי"ל). See here: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8859&st=&pgnum=111

Comment: Here is a series of shiurim that covers the issue:

 - http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/773278/Rabbi_Aaron_Rakeffet-Rothkoff/2012-3-4_Responsa_19_The_Psak_vs_the_Teshuva  The relevant portion of the shiur starts at about 33:45.
 - http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/773395/Rabbi_Aaron_Rakeffet-Rothkoff/2012-3-11_Responsa_20_Contradictions_in_the_Rulings_of_Maimonides 
 - http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/773696/Rabbi_Aaron_Rakeffet-Rothkoff/2012-3-18_Responsa_21_Does_'the_Code'_Conquer_All

Comment: Prof.Marc Schapiro brings both sides in hisbbook on the studies of the Rambam

Comment: I don't think there is such a case. There are even several cases in the responsa where the yad is challenged, and the Rambam, rather than retracting, says "I don't remember what I was thinking then, but I wouldn't have said it had I not been certain it was correct" and thereby upholds his previous psak while not defending it.

Comment: As @SethJ said, this question could be greatly improved with an example. As it's been almost four years and you have yet to include such an example, I'm going to VTC as unclear, as it makes an assumption without addressing why it's necessarily correct.

Answer (score 4):

[R. David Yosef](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3_(%D7%A8%D7%91)) in the introduction to the P'er Hador edition of Rambam's responsa quotes many who value the MT over the responsa, including [Hida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Yosef_David_Azulai) who writes in Birkei Yosef (OH 118:2) that it is obvious that the MT is to be followed over his responsa. In a similar vein, [Maharit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Trani) (HM: 7) writes that we generally follow books rather than responsa, since if the author intended to change his view he would have edited his book, and the responsum should therefore be assumed to be limited to that particular case. By this reasoning, if in the responsum Rambam indicated he erred, Maharit would agree that the responsum is followed.

R. Yosef also cites some who hold the opposite, such as the Radvaz (Divrei David 25, see also Shu"t 7:25). The [Netsiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naftali_Zvi_Yehuda_Berlin) similarly writes (Meshiv Davar 1:24) that reponsa of all poskim trump their general halakhic compilations.

For further discussion, see *Studies in Maimonides and His Interpreters* (2008) by [Marc Shapiro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_B._Shapiro), pp. 70-76.

Comment: There is an hakdama there from R' Ovadia himself that writes that even if we had rov rishonim neged the Rambam, but if it was foudn that the Rambam paskened the same thing in teshuvas as he did in the Mishnah Torah then we would therefore ultimately go after the psak of the Rambam.

Answer (score -1):

It's generally understood that the Mishna Torah was Rambam's last -- and therefore greatest -- work. We assume that he changed his mind over time from his responsa-writing period to when he wrote the Yad HaChazaka (i.e. Mishna Torah).

(Though much ink has been spilled about his responsum allowing conversion to Islam rather than death, vs. the Yad's prohibition.)

Comment: wrong. mora navukhim is his final book and we go by it when it contradicts the mt. for example the shiluah ha qan

Comment: any source for this?